# How to pass the same mutable Peekable to different functions in Rust

Tags: parsing, rust, iterator, mutable

I want to write a parser.
It seems practical to me to have a mutable `Iterator` that I can pass around to different parser functions.

I've tried to illustrated a simplified approach, which compiles but is not ideal yet.

```
fn main() {
    let tokens = vec!["fIrSt".to_string(), "SeConD".to_string(), "tHiRd".to_string(), "FoUrTh".to_string()];

    let parsed = parse_input(tokens);

    println!("{}", parsed);
}

fn parse_input(tokens: Vec<String>) -> String {
    let mut tokens_iter = tokens.iter();

    let upps = parse_upper(&mut tokens_iter);
    let lowers = parse_lower(&mut tokens_iter);

    upps + &lowers
}

fn parse_upper(tokens_iter: &mut Iterator<Item=&String>) -> String {
    let mut result = String::new();
    let token_1 = tokens_iter.next().unwrap().to_uppercase();
    let token_2 = tokens_iter.next().unwrap().to_uppercase();
    result.push_str(&token_1);
    result.push_str(&token_2);
    result
}

fn parse_lower(tokens_iter: &mut Iterator<Item=&String>) -> String {
    let mut result = String::new();
    let token_1 = tokens_iter.next().unwrap().to_lowercase();
    let token_2 = tokens_iter.next().unwrap().to_lowercase();
    result.push_str(&token_1);
    result.push_str(&token_2);
    result
}
```

**How the example works:**
Let's say I have some input, that has already been tokenized. Here it is represented by the `tokens` vector (`Vec<String>`).
Inside the outer `parse_input` function, the `Vec` gets transformed into an `Iterator` and then passed into different, specific parser functions. Here: `parse_upper` and `parse_lower`. In real life those could be "parse_if_statement" or "parse_while_loop" but which part of the `Iterator` gets worked on is not relevant for the question.
What is relevant is, that every call to next advances the cursor on the `Iterator`. So that every function consumes the pieces it needs.
This example compiles and gives the output: `FIRSTSECONDthirdfourth`

**I would like to be able to `peek()` into the `Iterator`, before I pass it to a function.** This is necessary to determine which function should actually be called. But everything I have tried with using a `Peekable` instead of an `Iterator` resulted in total lifetime and borrow chaos.

**Any suggestions on how to pass a `Peekable` instead of an `Iterator` in this case?**

Maybe using a `Peekable` as function parameter is a bad idea in the first place. Or maybe my `Iterator` approach is already wrong. All suggestions/hints are welcome.

Comment: If you're going to do a full-feature lexer/parser, just use a lib like [nom](https://docs.rs/nom/).

Comment: Why do you think this is a chaos ? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=32fcfd4ad7066860d026fcd7bfd42d5a , Simply you are telling that item in the iterator lives where the function gets called.

Comment: @ÖmerErden Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for, but couldn't quite work out. Lack of knowledge around generics and lifetimes on my end.

Comment: @niilz Ah ok! Usually, after you've lexed your code, you don't have owned strings, but slices. You're then allowed to "peek" them as much as you want.